# Relação N-to-N - Como juntar dois campos em um registro Postgresql -

Tags: postgresql, modelo-relacional

Em uma relação N-to-N
Tenho três tabelas "livro", "autor" e "livro_autor". Sendo os seguintes dados e estruturas:

**tblLivro:**

```
id_livro | nomelivro
'1'      ; 'O Cortiço'
'2'      ; 'O mulato'
'3'      ; 'Quimica Geral'
```

**tblAutor**

```
id_autor | nomeautor
'1'      ; 'Aluísio Azevedo'
'2'      ; 'John C. Kotz'
'3'      ; 'Paul M. Treichel'
'4'      ; 'Gabriela C. Weaver'
```

**tblLivro_Autor**

```
id_livro_autor | id_livro | id_autor. 
'1'            ; '1'      ; '1'
'2'            ; '2'      ; '1' 
'3'            ; '3'      ; '2' 
'4'            ; '3'      ; '3' 
'5'            ; '3'      ; '4'
```

Gostaria de fazer uma busca que retornaria o seguinte resutlado:

```
Livro           | Autor
'O Cortiço'     ; 'Aluísio Azevedo'
'O mulato'      ; 'Aluísio Azevedo'
'Quimica Geral' ; 'John C. Kotz, Paul M. Treichel, Gabriela C. Weaver'
```

Quando eu uso o seguinte comando SQL:

```
Select tblLivro.nomelivro, tblAutor.nomeautor, 
from tblLivro
left outer join tblLivro_Autor on tblLivro.id_livro=tblLivro_Autor.id_livro
left outer join tblAutor on tblLivro_Autor.id_autor=tblAutor.id_autor
```

Aparece o livro Quimica Geral  três vezes (um registror para cada autor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para agregar o valor de varias linhas em uma coluna pode usar a função [string_agg()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) que é equivalente o ao group_concat do MySQL

```
SELECT livro.nome_livro, string_agg(autor.nome_autor,',') FROM livro as l
LEFT OUTER JOIN livro_autor as la ON l.id_livro = la.id_livro
LEFT OUTER JOIN autor as a ON la.id_autor = a.id_autor
GROUP BY l.nome_livro
```

[Exemplo - sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/71f65/9)